# Update certain column of recordset from textbox value

Tags: php, sql, recordset

**room.php**

[image]

```
<input name = "room" type = "text" size="70"/>    

<a href="updateroom.php?roomid=<?=$row_Recordsetroomid['roomid'] ?>">Update</a>
```

**updateroom.php**

```
<?php
  mysql_connect('localhost','athirahhazira','1234');
  mysql_select_db("dbcollege");
  session_start();

  $sql = "UPDATE studentsroom set room='$strroom' WHERE roomid='$_GET[roomid]'";
  mysql_query($sql) or die('Error updating room status');

  header('Location:staff/room-staff.php');
?>
```

i can update if there is a default value such as :

```
  $sql = "UPDATE studentsroom set room='A206' WHERE roomid='$_GET[roomid]'";
```

but not the value from a textbox. could u help me with what i am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$sql = "UPDATE studentsroom set room='A206' WHERE roomid='".$_REQUEST['roomid']."'";
```

**Note:** your code can be sql injection. also `mysql_*` is deprecated use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

**Update2:**

add a form and submit button instead of hyperlink

```
<form method="post" action="updateroom.php" >
<input name = "room" type = "text" size="70"/>    
<input type="hidden" name="roomid" value="<?php echo $row_Recordsetroomid['roomid'];?>" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" />
</form>
```

AND **update.php**

```
<?php
  mysql_connect('localhost','athirahhazira','1234');
  mysql_select_db("dbcollege");
  session_start();

  $room = $_REQUEST['room']; 
  $roomid = $_REQUEST['roomid']; 

  $room = mysql_real_escape_string($room);
  $roomid = mysql_real_escape_string($roomid);

  $sql = "UPDATE studentsroom set room='$room' WHERE roomid='$roomid'";
  mysql_query($sql) or die('Error updating room status');

  header('Location:staff/room-staff.php');
?>
```

Comment: but i want to update based on the value from the textbox. not default value 'A206'

Comment: they were `updated` but it directs to an "Object not found!" page

Comment: yay. thanks! i was so confused after been working on this code so i accidently enter the wrong path. thank you! works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

The quotes for the index in the `$_GET` is missing. Trying to access array variables like `$array[key]` instead of `$array['key']`,  will trigger an error in most cases. So always try to use quotes for array indexes.

You can try with this.

```
$sql = "UPDATE studentsroom set room='A206' WHERE roomid='".$_GET['roomid']."'";
```

Comment: but i want to update based on the value from the textbox. not default value 'A206'

Comment: the textbox? its the name for the textbox room.

Comment: You cannot directly pass the value from input fields like textbox through url. For that you have to use either `<form>` or ajax call.

Comment: so if i were to change the hyperlink `Update` to a button, how will i update based on their room id by using `<form>`?